# Orchard: Add a wrapper to a shape in ShapeTableProvider ShapeTableBuilder

Tags: orchardcms

I have a shape named Account_UserDetails, that I'm trying to add some sort of wrapper to because it's just displaying as a bunch of LI's. I need a wrapper around the shape to control it better (like a UL). I tried the following but it doesnt seem to be showing in the browser at all. What am I doing wrong?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Descriptors;

namespace Onestop.Themes.LOEH
{
    public class ShapeDataProvider : IShapeTableProvider
    {
        public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Describe("Account_UserDetails").OnDisplaying(context => {
            context.Shape.Wrappers.Add("ul");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm puzzled about why you'd create a wrapper just to have everything in a UL tag. Isn't it way simpler to put that tag in the template for the shape itself?

Comment: I can't access the shape itself, only the Placement.info on the Theme level.

Comment: Why would you have access to `placement.info` but wouldn't be able to add a template override for the shape?

Answer (score 2):

Wrappers in Orchard are shapes, you can add them as following:

```cs
builder.Describe("Account_UserDetails").OnDisplaying(context => {
    context.Shape.Metadata.Wrappers.Add("Account_UserDetails_Wrapper");
});
```

Then you should add the wrapper shape as `Account_UserDetails_Wrapper.cshtml`:

```
<div>
    @DisplayChildren(Model)
</div>
```

if you need more info about wrappers, please refer to this [link](http://www.szmyd.com.pl/blog/wrapping-up-content-item-zones-in-custom-markup#.WA5Li4a8aaM)

Comment: this is what I want to do, but its not generating this shape at all. It actually only works if I add the following to the Placement.info file:

Comment: Account_UserDetails="/Header_Solo_Secondary:2;Wrapper=ListWrapper"/>

Comment: either, you add it in ShapeTableProvider or with placement.info you should create the wrapper shape itself

Comment: i have the shape created. it only shows the shape when i reference it in Placement.info though it doesnt generate the Model content. It appears empty. When I do it the other way nothing happens.

Comment: this is the correct solution. It didn't fix my issue because the entire shape isnt building for me, which is a separate problem due to the Assembly errors I'm getting.